# How to run javascript before onclick event of button in sharepoint app part which is asp.net page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

How  can run javascript before the event occurs. i m working on  project in which there is login button in sharepoint 2013 which includes various controls in asp.net now there is onbuttonclick() event which is called when we press a login button. i need to load my validation controls or javascript or jquery before onbuttonclick () event so please help me thanks in advance

some more description:-
i'm having .net validation controls(required field validater) in username & password field and there is a login button which has event onCLick() so as i click on login button 1st my page should display whether text field are blank or not but the problem is when i click login button without entering password and username its displays all(i:e it goes in database as well as shows the message of required field validator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your Validations for the User Name and Passwords are not fired and it is the standare asp.net page with Required field validators then , there may be some mistake in the code.

Check for the Valdation group for the Validators and check for the Login button property for the CauseValidation = True. If it is set to false the user is able to login without entering details

if you want to use javascript then there are KEy Press and KEyUp , KeyDown functions avaliable for your use.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});

$('#btnLogin').on('mouseover', function(){  
//Handle Mouse over event for the login and validate your Data  
});

$('#button').on('click', function(){  
    //validate on button click event  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In first case you should ask yourself or tell us what kind of event you like to fishing out. You need events called by user actions or auto. by the client. Maybe the following events could help you or help you thinking in a other way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //interact when DOM os ready
});

$('#button').on('mouseover', function(){
    //mouse over button
});

$('#button').on('click', function(){
    //clicky-clacky
});
```

By the way. You should use JS-Frameworks like [jquery](http://jquery.com/).